# Color not showing at UINavBar in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I have a UINavBar and I set the color to blue (manually, not programmatically,) and when I run it on the simulator it shows it like the following. (Though in xcode, the navBar is blue.)

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this navbar instance is actually being used? Try cleaning your project. Sometimes I notice that Interface Builder resources aren't put in the application bundle because they are thought to be identical to previous versions.

Comment: What do you mean navBar 'instance'? At the outline navigator, I selected the Navigation Controller Scene. I then selected the navigation bar and changed the color. Did I not do it correctly?

Comment: Are you initializing any navigation objects in code? What I mean by instance is that the particular navbar item. If you created a new one in code, there may be a mismatch.

Comment: I did try to make a new UINavigationBar earlier. I then realized it was wrong, so I erased it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the viewController that is flexible for the ipad and iphone. Now in that viewController I inserted a navigation controller for each viewController. (Which surprisingly xcode lets you do that. And at the time I didn't know it was wrong.) So I set the bar tint color at the navigation controller that was not the first one. (It was the second view navigation controller) It therefore had a conflict of which color to take, the color from the first navigation controller, or the current navigation controller.